# how to change background color for qtabbar empty space pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt, stylesheet

I need to change background color for the empty space of the QTabbar like in image below, I can already use style sheet to change tabbar but it change tabs only not the empty space next to tabs (red bordered area)

I am using PyQt 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you can make it either via:

`tabWidget->setStyleSheet("QTabBar { background-color: red; }");
tabWidget->setDocumentMode(true);`

But it doesn't look good.

Or via:

`tabWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true);
QPalette pal = tabWidget->palette();
pal.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::red);
tabWidget->setPalette(pal);`

Or just create QWidget with some background and insert QTabWidget on top of it.