# PyQt5 Tabwidget tab bar blank area background color

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

hi everyone , how to fill background color in empty space tab bar area.
 i checked this link: [how to change background color for qtabbar empty space pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100180/how-to-change-background-color-for-qtabbar-empty-space-pyqt) , but not success.

here is my stylesheet:

```py
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet('''
            QTabBar::tab{padding: 0px;}
            QTabBar::tab { height: 150px; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;}
            QTabBar::tab {background-color: rgb(34, 137, 163);color: white;}

            QTabBar::tab:selected {background-color: rgb(48, 199, 184,);
                color: #000000
            }

            QTabWidget>QWidget>QWidget{background: WHITE;}
            QTabWidget>{background: WHITE;}

            QTabWidget::pane {top: 0px;}
            QTabWidget::tab-bar {right: 0px;}
            QTabBar { background: transparent; }
        ''')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the [`documentMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#documentMode-prop).

If it's `False` (the default), you have to set the TabWidget background, and ensure that its [`autoFillBackground()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) is set to True; this is very important, as Qt automatically unselect it when setting a stylesheet.
Note that, in this case, the background will be "around" the whole tab widget too, if don't want it, just disable the border.

```
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet('''
        QTabWidget {
            background: magenta;
            border: none;
        }
        QTabBar::tab {
            background: green;
        }
    ''')
```

If the document mode is on, instead, you can just set the background for the tab bar:

```
    self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet('''
        QTabBar {
            background: magenta;
        }
        QTabBar::tab {
            background: green;
        }
    ''')
```

Comment: @DhurjatiRiyanBorah I just checked with your stylesheet and it works. Ensure that you're not setting the palette at the same time, **always** check if the autoFillBackground is set **everytime** you update the stylesheet in Designer, and remove the ">" in the `QTabWidget>{background: WHITE;}` line.